# FOR loop in SQL replacement

Tags: sql

I'm new at SQL and one thing that I've just learned reading other posts is that there are no FOR loop constructs in SQL and it is not a good practice trying emulate it somehow.

Anyhow, I've got this problem that I would approach iteratively: a table has 2 columns, `fav_retail_id` and `user_id`. The first column contains the retails added among favorites and the second the users that added the correspondent retail among favorites.

Now, I'd like to know how many users have the retail with id = 42 among their favorite retails. I simply wrote the following:

```
select count(id) from favorite_retails
where retail_id = 42
```

And this seems to work pretty well. My point now is that I want to do the same for some other retails, say those with id = 31, 54, 98.

Is there a way to iteratively get this information?
Thanks for support, A.

Comment: Have a look at the `IN` keyword: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: SQL is a declarative language - you focus on the 'what' and not on the 'how'

Comment: You can also `right join` the `favorite_retails` table with a table that contains the desired `retail_id`. This is probably what you want if there is more than a handful of id after the `in` keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `group by`, if you want the answer for each one:

```
select retail_id, count(id)
from favorite_retails
where retail_id in ( 31, 54, 98 )
group by retail_id;
```

Remove the `where` if you want the answer for all `retail_id`s.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is usually about set-based operations and quite rarely about iterative operations. In your case you could use simple `group by` with filter by `retail_id`

```
select
    retail_id,
    count(id)
from favorite_retails
where
    retail_id in (31, 54, 98)
group by
    retail_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
select count(id) from favorite_retails
where retail_id in ( 31, 54, 98 )
```